# Testing a recursive Celery task

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a function, lets call him `fob`. His task is to just check some things, make sure they are all ok and call another Celery task for further processing.

One of the variables he is checking is.. fuzzy. If this variable is not as it should be, simply reschedules himself like `fob.delay(whatever)` up to a certain threshold .

I want to test `fob`. But I'm not interested in what happens after he executes himself again. I just want to make sure `fob` reschedules himself with the same arguments and incrementing his self-control counter.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Write a `check_all` function which checks everything and returns `True` if everything is OK.

```
def check_all():
    # returns true if all conditions are satisfied.
    return True
```

Now write your `fob` fucntion which checks everything and reschedules itself.

```
def fob(*args, **kwargs):
    if check_all():
        #go to next task if everything is ok
        call_next_task.delay()
    else:
        # call itself again
        fob.delay(*args, **kwargs)
```